# jquery calculated result should show image due to result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a calculation which should show different images or text due to the result that is given. 
for example, if the result is between 3 and 7 there should be image 1, if it is between 8 and 12 -> image 2.

i made a jsfiddle with the actual state: http://jsfiddle.net/utSYb/

```
<form id="calx">
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>Variable 1 </td><td><input id="th" type="text" name="th[]" value="77" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Variable 2 </td><td><input id="ah" type="text" name="ah[]" value="132" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Variable 3</td><td><select name="ih" id="ih"><option value="45">1"</option><option value="51">2"</option></select></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Result</td><td><input id="x" type="text" name="x[]" value="" data-formula="($ah-$th-$ih+2)" /></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

for your info, i am using this script: http://www.xsanisty.com/project/calx/

thanks

Comment: Okay, I can't see where you even tried to use `img` tags and `src`, attributes, so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: i do not know how to code the calculation "between" --> show image. there is no image at the moment. do not have to be an image. can also just be a div which is changed from display: none to display:block f.e.

Comment: `if (result >= 3 && result <= 7) {...} else if (result >= 8 && result <= 12) {...}` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('input').on('change', function () {
    var x = $('#x').val();
    if (x > 3 && x < 7) {
        //code to show image
    }
    //elseif for other statements and so on...
});
```

Comment: This will show image when 'x' is between 4 & 6 as opposed to 3 & 7 . . .

Comment: @PatDobson OP asked for between 3 and 7 so he wants then 4-5-6 then

Comment: works like a charm. but if i change the value to f.e. 90 the image is still there. can i use else {} to display:none the image?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will sort you out:

```
if( result >= 3 && result <= 7 ){
    ... show image 1 ...
}else if( result >= 8  && result <= 12){
    ... show image 1 ...
}else{
    ... show default image . . .
}
```